# Can not rename publisher name in visual studio gallery

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, msdn, visual-studio-gallery

I changed my name on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/.../, but I still see my old name in `CREATED BY` field on my extension page. Even if I publish a new extension.

[image]

What should I do to rename my publisher name?

Comment: Maybe you could share a screen shot, sorry for that we couldn't visit that link in your issue. In addition, if it was related to the VS gallery site usage, I suggest you discuss it from the Gallery official site directly.

Comment: Ok. I added screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I know is that the VS Gallery site has been updated to the VS Marketplace. Maybe you could submit a feature request like this one:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/331878-visual-studio-marketplace/suggestions/13957530-have-a-question-and-answer-section.

Or you could get support from the Marketplace directly using "General marketplace help" here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/billing/_shared/qa-marketplace-support

Answer (score 0):

Marketplace is working now at full strength.

Now I can rename displaying name, but I can't rename ID. Or I can create new publisher.